# Open source/Paid Automation tool to test Tableau Desktop

Tags: automation, tableau-api, desktop-application

We are looking for Open source/Paid Automation tool to test various versions of Tableau Desktop.

I tried alot but cant find any thing.Can any one please help

Comment: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) says specifically that this sort of question is not among them. It will greatly improve your experiences here if you spend a few minutes taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to better understand the site and what is acceptable here before posting.

Comment: okay..sorry.. If you can guide me about any website or tool that solve my query so it will be big help for me

Comment: I can't do that, because your question is off-topic here. If the question is off-topic, that means you *cannot ask it here*, period. That's what *off-topic* means. Try asking at Quora.